Delete API in spring
I have a problem.
I have two tables: categoria and list
I want that when I delete an element of categoria by id, every elements of table list with the attribute category equal to the id and the attribute whitelist equal to one are deleted too.
In my CategoriaRepository I do this:
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM list l WHERE l.categoria = :id AND l.whitelist = 1", nativeQuery = true)
void deleteListsByCategoriaIdAndWhitelist(@Param("id") Long id);

@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM categoria c WHERE c.id = :id", nativeQuery = true)
void deleteCategoriaById(@Param("id") Long id);

@Modifying
@Transactional
default void deleteCategoriaAndLists(Long categoriaId) {
    deleteListsByCategoriaIdAndWhitelist(categoriaId);
    deleteCategoriaById(categoriaId);
}

In my CategoriaController i do this:
@DeleteMapping("/categoria/{id}")
public void delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
  categoriaRepository.deleteCategoriaAndLists(id);
}

This delete the category but not the elements in list.
Someone can help me please?

If it is one to many then on delete cascade is not setup i think

You can have a look at Cascade.REMOVE on the 'Categoria; entity
https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-remove-vs-orphanremoval
